# How do you use draw points visible on high dense screens

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a space look to my game and wanted to add stars to the background. I decided to make a `float[] points` and make it randomized. I then use the `canvas.drawPoints(points, white);`. This works very well on my emulator. On a phone, you can barely see the points. I am wondering if I can have points bigger than a pixel (I know that makes no sense) or use a method like `drawRects(points, size, paint);`. Using a for loop is not efficient and makes the game laggy. Is there another way or do I have to live with the lag.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider drawing the stars with lines. Consider creating a `Star` [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html).

Comment: Oh I didn't know the star shape existed let me check that out thanks!

Comment: I was suggesting creating one. But Google may well yield one.

Comment: I could use 4 points next to each other to simulate a square. But this would use a lot of room. Right now I have an array of 400 int. if you multiply that by 4 I have 1600 int variables. This would be insane if it goes up to 9 or 16 pixels in a square. Is there anyway to stop this. I just don't want to burn up all of the device's memory on the background or all of the device's cpu.

Comment: Google "Sprite Android".

Comment: I'm not trying to make shapes but am trying to make points visible. Maybe a rectangle. But, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way than just drawRect()\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to different densities of your emulator and phone.
1 px on different screens have different physical size. You should use dp (dip or density independent pixels) and then convert it to the pixels.

So your code should look like:

```
ind dpRadius = 1;
Resources r = getResources();
float pxRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpRadius, r.getDisplayMetrics());

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(pxRadius);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

// your drawPoints code ...
```

Comment: Sweet, I will try that out. Thanks!